# Search is not showing full, correct results

Tags: bug, status-norepro, search

When I search for CSS, the system shows only one result. There are 22,158 questions tagged [css](/questions/tagged/css). What are the criteria for searching? Does search not take tags into consideration? Does it consider only the title?

See all questions tagged [css](/questions/tagged/css) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/search/?q=css

Seems correct to me. Make sure you're not on the featured tab, since that will only show featured questions in that tag.